# Qt QTableWidget Header Color

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I would like to change the color of *a* vertical header cell in a QTableWidget.

Here is my (failed) attempt:

```
QTableWidgetItem* vHeaderItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
vHeaderItem->setBackgroundColor(QColor("yellow"));
ui.tableWidget->setVerticalHeaderItem(r, vHeaderItem);
```

I have no idea why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I am having this problem right now with Qt 4

Comment: From memory, there is a bug, but don't quote me on that.  I think if you do a bit more searching, you'll find some posts about this somewhere else on the Qt site.  I haven't used Qt in ages and so don't remember to well...  Sorry.  I think maybe to change the colour you need to change the XML file, but again, I don't fully remember.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
vHeaderItem->setBackgroundColor(Qt::yellow);
```

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't (at least for me).  Thanks for the suggestion though.